# scroll view's leading and trailing constraint messed up in rtl language

Tags: swift, rtl-language

Scroll view showing correct layout with ltr(English) while I switched the language to rtl(arabic) scroll view's leading and trailing constraint are distorted, they are more shifted towards left

Comment: Please share code, screenshot, you have tried till now

Answer (score 0):

Arabic among other languages is written right to left and `leading` + `trailing` are aligning towards that. If you want it static you should use `left` and `right`

Comment: I used 20 left and 20 right then it was ok in english but shifted towards left in arabic but  as I changed 20 left and -20 right it was fine in both.Can u explain why??